# Casting Interface in Activity

Tags: java, android

The matter is that, before this time, I implemented `interfaces` in `Activity`, values ​​of methods set in `Fragment`. That is, in `onAttach()` initialized, and then where to call the `interface` method called. Example:

```
interface OnNumberChangeCallback{
    void onSuccess();
}
```

In `Fragment`:

```
OnNumberChangeCallback onNumberChangeCallback;

onAttach(Context context){
    onNumberChangeCallback = (OnNumberChangeCallback) context;
}
```

etc.

I want to initialize the `interface` in `BaseActivity`. And in `Fragment` to implement this `interface`. When I try to initialize in `onCreate` method this way:

```
onNumberChangeCallback = (OnNumberChangeCallback) this;
```

I get the error:

```
BaseActivity cannot be cast to OnNumberChangeCallback
```

**Question**: How to properly initialize the `interface` in `Activity`?

Comment: You don't implement in the interface, you implement in the Activity. Or your Activity doesn't implement, as the error says

Comment: Why do you need to cast, though? If `this` does implement that interface, the cast is redundant

Comment: I want to call the `onSuccess()` method in `Activity` when I click the `button`, and so that the `textView` in `Fragment` immediately changes the text

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve]? Where are you actually implementing the interface?

Comment: You can just call `fragment.setSuccess` directly from the Activity

Comment: I will try)    .......

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want the **Fragment** to implement the interface, and have the Activity store a reference to it somehow.

Your interface:

```
interface OnNumberChangeCallback {
    void onSuccess();
}
```

To implement it in your fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnNumberChangeCallback {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        // TODO
    }

    // other fragment methods, like onCreateView() etc
}
```

And to save the listener in your activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private OnNumberChangeCallback callback;

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);

        if (fragment instanceof OnNumberChangeCallback) {
            callback = (OnNumberChangeCallback) fragment;
        }
    }

    // other activity methods, like onCreate() etc
}
```

Then, to use the callback, you could write something like this anywhere inside your activity:

```
public void onButtonClick() {
    if (callback != null) {
        callback.onSuccess();
    }
}
```

The root of this solution is that `FragmentActivity` (which is a superclass of `AppCompatActivity`) has a method `onAttachFragment()` that is called any time a Fragment is attached to your activity. In the same way you could cast your `Context` to an interface inside a fragment by using `onAttach()`, you can cast a `Fragment` to an interface using `onAttachFragment()`.

Documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onAttachFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)

PS: This answer provides a very generic solution, and one that should work for almost any way you're adding Fragments to your Activity. If, however, you *know* that Fragments will be added in a particular way, you could probably do something much simpler than implementing `onAttachFragment()`... you could just cast the Fragment as you add it to your activity, like this:

```
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    callback = fragment;

    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.content, fragment, "fragmentTag")
            .commit();
```

Comment: I wanted to ask a very similar question when I have found this. I'm using the `OnAttach` method in my fragment and cast the interface instance to an Activity so later on I can call the interface implementation in the caller activity. The question I have is what does it mean exactly when you cast an interface to an Activity?  It works for sure and I can communicate data from my fragment to the caller activity, but I dont understand what does it really realize. Would you mind enlight me about this?

Comment: Just to be precise I acutally cast the interface instance to a Context (and not to an Activity)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cast context to interface you can not. I use abstract class and extends AppCompatActivity and use abtract method in this abstract class.

```
public abstract class AbstractActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   public abstract  void someAbstractMethod();

}
```

---

```
    public class MainActivity extends AbstractActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    @Override
    public void someAbstractMethod() {

    }
}
```

Now you can cast your context to AbstractActivity and call the method.

Comment: Where's the Fragment that the question is asking about?

Comment: In the question, fragment has onAttach(Context context) method. Now you can cast your context variable to AbstractActivity.

Comment: how to initialize it